# MySQL: 4 tables migration to 1 table

Tags: mysql, database-migration

Hello I'm not a programmer.
I'm just a minecraft gamer.
please help me. T_T

[This is what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJbUa.jpg)
   * this is my minecraft server's zone protection plugin's database.

[1. I want to copy all id, world_id (PK) from Schema1.region](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BS4WU.jpg)
   * solved!

[2. I want to insert min_x, min_y, min_z, max_x, max_y, max_z
   from Schema1.region_cuboid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFuvd.jpg)
   * insert? join? I don't know... sorry.

[3. I want to insert user_id from Schema1.region_players](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sR9is.jpg)
   * and if owner is 1, put user_id on master column,
     or if owner is 0, put user_id on member column.
   * master column is always one person, (or null)
     but member column is not always one person. (or null)
     so member column value must be place with Array type.
     ex) [67, 1744]

[4. I want to replace user_id (int) to name (string)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxHXZ.jpg)
   * '44' replace to 'kim' (yes!)
       '1744' replace to '17kim' (no...)

Comment: Please format question properly.

Comment: Both examples are terribly structured